# Laravel 5.7 Eloquent memory issues

Tags: php, laravel, memory-leaks

I'm running the latest version of Laravel (v5.7.19), and have a little issue.
I have a seeder than is running loop inside another one, and doing a simple query.

```
foreach ($tests as $test) {
    foreach ($anothers as $another) {
        Test::where('column', 123);
    }
}
```

This runs without any issues. I'm using memory_get_usage for the memory check.
As soon as I change the line to *Test::where('column', 123)->first();* I run into huge memory problems. Does anyone have any ideas around this one?

Comment: Without knowing what's in that record, no. Start double-checking your code and values to see where the leak might be.

Comment: Probably has to with the nested loop containing an expensive query. You might want to consider not looping but using relationships.

Comment: Can you post your actual code, which can help us optimise this?

Comment: Did you index the table correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming that this isnt your actual code.

Calling the functions `->first()` or `->get()` means you are fetching data from the database. Before that, Eloquent is just building your query, not actually loading any data.

I suspect you are pushing the result of your query into an array, possibly resulting in a huge array that is causing the memory issue. If your seeder is contained inside the loop and the objects are disposed of, i dont see why you would encounter memory issues.

Try unsetting all the variables you dont need inside the loop to not run out of memory.